# How to get value and attributes of span

Tags: jquery

My code is :

```
<br>
var value = $("#editor").jqxEditor('val');
```

value="`<div><span style="font-weight:bold">Welcome</span></div>`";

Then how do i get span text and its attributes font-weight values in variables.

Comment: `$(span).find('span').text()` and `$(span).find('span').css('font-weight')`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find) method:

```
var value = $("#editor").jqxEditor('val');
var span =  value.find('span');
```

And to get its attributes, you can use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method:

```
var attrs = span.attr('style');
```

Comment: is value string? if yes, you need to parse as html first.

Answer (score 0):

Font weight of 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        value = '<div><span class="test_span" style="font-weight:bold">Welcome</span></div>';
        alert($(value).find('span.test_span').text());
        alert($(value).find('span.test_span').css('font-weight'));

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If u have no class then use this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        value = '<div><span style="font-weight:bold">Welcome</span></div>';
        alert($(value).find('span').text());
        alert($(value).find('span').css('font-weight'));
    });
```

Comment: Font weight of 400 is the same as normal, and 700 is the same as bold

Comment: its working but gives all span text available on the page,not specific i.e. "value"

Comment: add a class to that span .

Comment: The value comes from jqxeditor, so that it gives value as string and from that string ,i have to find span value i.e. Welcome and attribute also,but it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

Add class to span.let me say class = "foo";

```
$('.foo').text(); //to get value
$('.foo').attr();//to get attribute
```

Comment: ***span has no value***

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the text in a jquery object and based on that object get the text and the fond weight:

```
var value='<div><span style="font-weight:bold">Welcome</span></div>';
var text = $(value).find('span').text();
var fontWeight = $(value).find('span').css('font-weight');
console.log(text+' '+fontWeight)
```

see:https://jsfiddle.net/43xnfpqu/